# BQ Aquaris Ubuntu Phone sync with thunderbird on computer?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, thunderbird, sync

How (with which app)  can I synchronize contacts between Ubuntu phone (BQ Aquaris) and Thunderbird on my computer?

Comment: Why is this downvoted, and voted to close as unclear? The question is pretty explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly sync contacts with an Ubuntu phone at the moment. You will need to have your contacts in Google for example, and then sync both the phone and Thunderbird with your Google account. There's currently no other supported way of syncing contacts between the phone and a PC.